# One of two Travis CI builds failing: how can that be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, travis-ci

I'm a little confused about what Travis CI does. In an OpenSource project I'm contributing to we have as a problem - amongst others - that Travis is currently not passing. Problem is: In development locally every test of the suite passes but one (of two) Travis builds seems to fail and I don't quite understand why. Here's the PR where you'll find Travis' reports: https://github.com/magdalena19/lberg-map/pull/228

This is what `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
before_script:
- psql -c 'create database "lberg-map_test";' -U postgres
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.3.1
addons:
  code_climate:
    repo_token: <secret>
after_success:
- bundle exec codeclimate-test-reporter
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: travis_ci_test
env:
  global:
  - secure:
  ...
```

Secondly we've observed multiple times Travis CI not passing - where local runs of the test suites did. What we did sometimes was to implement neglectable changes to some part within the code, try again and then it worked. What are possible explanations for this behavior?

I'd be glad if anyone could give me a clue!

thx and regards,
Andi

Comment: They both seem to be passing now, so who knows? Perhaps you have something in a test that is not entirely deterministic (timing-related, maybe). Also, regarding the two builds: one is a build of the PR's branch; and the other is a build of the PR merged with master - so a single failure could also be merge-related.

Comment: Yeah, the two builds passed after committing subtle changes, BUT: Now I've merged and... the master is now failing oO Wasn't that the sense of one of the builds to test against that?